# Function to return value of next level

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a made a query which returns the VP SPOC  of an organization.Now i want that if level 1's VP SPOC is null then the function should return level 2's VP SPOC. if level 2's VP SPOC is missing then level 3's VP SPOC should be returned.
Any help will be appreciated.

My query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT aou.name parent_org,
           aou.organization_id organization_id,
           LEVEL,
           XX_ROLL_VPHR_PKG.XX_GET_SPOC(aou.organization_id,
                                        'VPHR',
                                        TRUNC(SYSDATE),
                                        'person_id')
      FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS OSE, HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS AOU
     WHERE aou.organization_id = ose.organization_id_child
START WITH organization_id_child = :p_org_id
CONNECT BY organization_id_child = PRIOR organization_id_parent
  ORDER BY LEVEL;
```

Output:

```
Organization name               org id  level   VP SPOC
Investor Accounting SP PR          398      1      null
Serviced Portfolio PR              330      2      null
PR Operations                      106      3      1944
```

So if level 1's VP SPOC is missing then level 2's vp spoc should be checked and finally level 3's  VP hr should be returned

Comment: Is the output you show here is the expected output? Also when you say next level, does it mean next level SPOC of the same organization? May be you help us with some sample data for your both tables!

Comment: Hi @MaheswaranRavisankar. By Level i mean the level column i am getting in the sql query. and yes the output is the actual output i am getting from the above given query